# display on hover of div stops working after running script toggle

Tags: .net, css, asp-classic

I'm trying to make a div `lolcake` appear in another `panel_toggle1` div either:

- when mouse hovers over another div `panel_toggle1`
- or toggles on and off each click on the `panel_toggle1` click

http://jsfiddle.net/Fa7Ct/

hover works fine, but when I click on the `panel_toggle1` and back, **the hover stops working**. Why is that?

[EDITED] script (NOTE: some code is removed from this script to make it easier to read - and yes the problem still occurs):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var toggle_height1 = false;
    $("#panel_toggle1").click(function () {

        toggle_height1 = !toggle_height1;

        if (toggle_height1 == true) {
            $('.lolcake').css("display", "block");
        } else {
            $('.lolcake').css("display", "none");
        }
    });
});
```

working CSS:

```
.lolcake
{
    display: none;
}

#panel_toggle1:hover .lolcake
{
    display: block;
}
```

(if needed) aspx

```
<!-- GAME1 PANEL TOGGLE -->
    <div id="panel_toggle1">
        <div class="lolcake" style="position:absolute">text</div><img src="images/image.png" alt=""/>
    </div>
```

I've used other functions like `toggle()` and `show()` `hide()`, but all have the same effect.

Comment: You could include all the elements that appear in your JS into your aspx(html) code, so we could recreate the problem in order to analyze it. Or you could just paste a jsFiddle link.

Comment: exactly, to figure out what is wrong we need all the elements in your code. for example $("#panel1").slideToggle("slow");
        $("#container-right").animate()  now where is #panel and #container-right div's??

Comment: I've added a fibble if this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your css

```
#panel_toggle1:hover .lolcake
{
display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: sorry this doesn't really solve my problem. I'm aiming for a solution that will allow me to toggle via hover **and** clicking (problem is hover over the `panel_toggle1` stops working, button works fine)

Comment: Amazing, exactly what I wanted :)! Thx!!